# How to Implement Couchbase ComplexKey with List<String> in java

Tags: java, couchbase

I have problem to implement complexkey of Couchbase Java. 
Here is how my java code look like:
Query q2 = new Query();

```
List<String> p = new ArrayList<String>();
p.add("person1000");
p.add("person1");
ComplexKey ck = ComplexKey.of(p);
q2.setKeys(ck);
```

Everytime it returns error `Java function call failed: Failed to access the view.` How to implement ArrayList to ComplexKey? I am using version 1.3.1.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I got my answer myself. It was stupid question but have to share it :-) 
it will work when we change the above code as following :-)

```
ComplexKey ck = ComplexKey.of(p.toArray());
```

Comment: Please mark your answer as solved so this doesn't question say open - thanks!

Comment: Thank you @DaveRigby, just it did not allowed me because I had to wait one day for self answer so could not marked as solved. I will mark tomorrow.